# Resizing image in table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem resizing the image in the yellow div. I can't set `max-width` to 100% because it disappear and also can't set a fixed width to the divs because I need it be dynamic.
How could I resize the image without setting width?

```css
.container{
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  display: table;
}

.opcion{
  display: table-cell;
  background: yellow;
}

.opcion img{ }

.texto{
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="opcion">
        <img src="https://www.google.com.ar/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">   
    </div>

    <div class="texto ti-ab-d">
        <label for="test"><p>Prueba</p></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox**

```css
.container{
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.opcion{
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.opcion img {
  width: 100%;
}

.texto{
  background: green; 
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="opcion">
        <img src="https://www.google.com.ar/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">   
    </div>

    <div class="texto ti-ab-d">
        <label for="test"><p>Prueba</p></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but then the image's width wouldn't be the original supposing that the image it's smaller than 30%

Comment: @Polo I think i understand what you are looking for now, i suggest you do this with Flexbox, i updated my answer.

Comment: Ok that is what I was looking for. The thing now is that if I put my divs with flex inside a table the content overlaps or disappear eventully. But that's another subject, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to delete this

```
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :) This would stretch image I believe to fit

```
.opcion.image {
  background-image: url("file.png");
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I could not make it work. The image didn't stretch the div.